# Are there any "dark launch" frameworks or libraries for .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web

I'm looking to start doing dark launches and ramp ups in our production site (ASP.Net Webforms / MVC). Are there any existing libraries or frameworks for .Net that help with this or do I just need to roll my own?

Clarification:

I want to build a feature and push it to production without users seeing it then have the ability to turn that feature on or off for a particular user, group of users, customer, etc.

**EDIT**

There are libraries / frameworks available in other languages for this.

Examples:

- Ruby: https://github.com/jamesgolick/rollout
- Python: https://github.com/asenchi/proclaim

I'm about to start building one but want to make sure I'm not re-inventing the wheel.

My question is: Are there any similar libraries for frameworks for .Net?

Comment: It sounds like this isn't any different than enabling/disabling features based on permissions? Do we need a library for that?

Comment: I'm referring to pre-release features that should not be available to my entire user base yet. The question states that I want to do ramp ups. How would I use permissions to make a feature available to 10 percent of my users?

Comment: Give a permission to only 10% of your users ;)

Comment: How practical would managing permissions be if I wanted a random sampling? Or if I wanted  to adjust the sampling size? Only managing permissions doesn't seem applicable to this question.

Comment: @Pat "then have the ability to turn that feature on or off for a particular user, group of users, customer, etc." is really the definition of a permission-based system. He is doing this from a web app, so it should be trivial to give permissions as randomly or in whatever sample size he wants. Now, if he's asking for a library that chooses for him who gets the perms applied, that's a different question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the term to search for is not "dark launch" but instead "feature flipper". I have now found a couple of libraries that do this in .Net:

- Flipper by Michael Sarchet: https://github.com/msarchet/flipper
- FlipIt by Tim Scott: https://github.com/timscott/flipit